# Setting Up Company-wide Accounts Using Meteor

Tags: javascript, authentication, meteor

I'm working on a B2B app that requires company-wide accounts, then user accounts within each company. So Company ABC would be an account, then Employee 1 and Employee 2 would each have sub-accounts within the Company ABC account. That way each employee can have their own view and submit tickets that the other employee can see.

I've tried playing around with Meteor-Roles from alanning but can't quite figure it out. Has anyone else tried this account system with Meteor?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Have you used the basic account packages? The roles package only extends them https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/adding-user-accounts

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't come with a company-wide accounts system, only individual accounts. I'd need to group users into a company account. It's that extended functionality that I'm struggling with. How do you group some accounts into one large one and other accounts into another - all that'll scale? Thanks for replying!

Comment: You can just create users like normal, then add their `userId` to a particular document in your `Companies` collection

Comment: Thinking through your suggestion, I could ask the first person to sign up for an account then allow him or her to send email invites. Within those email invites I could have the userID. Otherwise, I wouldn't know how to set and prove that they are allowed in that company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've accomplished this in the past by doing something similar to what @ObbyOss suggested.

Here's what I did:

1. Allow a user to sign up to your app (this user will be the "admin" user - set using the alanning-roles package). When creating the user, assign a randomly generated ID (this will be your companyId).
2. Allow the admin user to create new users from within the app ('add new user' -  enter the user's name, email address, and assign a random password - then email the user with their credentials, and prompt them to change their password on first log in attempt
3. When admin user creates this new user, set the 'companyId' field in the db for the sub-user to be the companyId of the admin user. This ensures that all your users under the umbrella of that randomly generated comapnyId belong to the same company.
4. Whenever you need to make user-specific calls, user the user's Id. Whenever you need to get all users that belong to a company, you can get use the company's Id.

Hope that makes sense! This is a common use-case, and the method I've outlined above has worked perfectly for me in the past. If you have any questions, please feel free to reach out.

Comment: Thanks for the validation and taking my ideas a step further, flawless. Since you've done this before, do you have a tutorial written up anywhere or open sourced code? I'm still rather new to writing apps. I think my hardest implementation is the email and prompting them to change their password - I guess the validation aspect. Thanks again for your help!